# Checkboxes and Custom List in WPF with MVVM Pattern

Tags: c#, wpf, list, xaml, mvvm

I have a problem in Windows 8 apps with WPF. I have a User Control where there are seven check boxes for Week Days. Monday, Tuesday, Wednesday, Thursday, Friday, Saturday, Sunday.

What I want to do is I want a list of Days which are checked in User Control's Viewmodel.

What is the correct way to do this ? That list will be used in the model so I want a separate class for list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the ViewModel of a Day, add a Selected property.

In the View of a Day, add a checkbox and bind it (TwoWay) to the Selected property of the DayViewModel

In the ViewModel of a Week, add an observable collection of Days.

In the View of a Week , add an ItemsControl and bind it to the Days property of the WeekViewModel and use the DayView as the ItemTemplate.

This way you can easily get the selected days in the WeekViewModel:

```
var selectedDaysQuery = Days.Where(day=>day.Selected);
```